# Can't access HttpRuntime.Cache in .NET Standard class library

Tags: c#, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I'm beginning to port our .NET Framework class libraries to .NET Standard 2.0. Right away, I'm running into an issue with not finding an equivalent to:

```
private readonly System.Web.Caching.Cache _cache = HttpRuntime.Cache;
```

I understand that a .NET Standard project needs to support multiple platforms so might not be able to handle logic like this from System.Web anymore, but I need a way to access http caching within class libraries. I'm sure this is a very common request as developers port over their applications, any suggestions?

Note: I saw this link about [System.Runtime.Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-2.1), is that the new way to handle http caching?

Comment: [this API is not supported in .net standard/.net core](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache)

Comment: [replacement is here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory/)

Answer (score 4):

You can use System.Runtime.Caching using nuget packages

Then use following methods to manage cache

To Add:

```
MemoryCache.Default.Add(key, value, new CacheItemPolicy { SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(some hours, some minutes, some seconds) });
```

To Get:

```
return MemoryCache.Default.Get(key);
```

To Remove:

```
MemoryCache.Default.Remove(key);
```